# Invoking a function by address

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am  trying to learn a few different methods of calling functions by address.

```
bool gl_draw_text(uint x, uint y, uint color, uint alpha, char *fmt);
```

This function is what I'm calling. The following, is how I'm currently calling it. (And it works fine.)

```
static void glDrawText(char* text, int x, int y)
{
DWORD func = 0x10057970;

__asm
{
    push text
    push 255
    push 14
    push y
    push x
    call dword ptr [func]
    }
}
```

The method I want to use is this one.

```
void Hack()
{
    bool (draw*)(uint, uint, uint, uint, char*);
    draw = 0x10057970;
    (draw)(20, 20, 14, 255, "Text");
}
```

But, I don't know how to properly cast the address to the function to make it work\compile. ?

There is also a method that uses a virtual function, I'm curious about how that method works too. (I can also use MS Detours, to hook, then call the function like that, how does that method work behind the scenes, if you know.)

So to be clear, I'm just asking for various methods of accomplishing this task, but listed a few I'm curious about after reading about them, etc,.

Comment: Does it not work, or does it not compile?  Generally, the actual address of a function will change when you recompile, or even when you run the same program again.

Comment: @Neil, it's not magic, it's a real address, of a real function. @aramadia, it's like I said, a casting issue.

Comment: @TheMonster My point is, how do you know that is the address of the function?

Comment: Because I do? Not sure why it's important, you should just take my word for it. But, if you really must know. I know it's the address, because I am hacking a game, this function is part of another DLL hacking the same game, I know the person who wrote said other DLL, they told me the offset where I could find it, I debugged the .exe, checked, and sure enough, there it was.

Comment: @TheMonster Why should I take your word for anything? And the DLL can quite easily be loaded at another address, depending on about a zillion things.

Comment: Whatever, you don't know what you're talking about. If it worked like you seem to think it does, then function hooking would be impossible. (MS Detours, Microsofts own hooking library, uses addresses for hooks, functions do not move around on their own.)

Comment: @TheMonster As they say on usenet, *plonk*

Comment: Epic Fail, or perhaps a day in the life of Neil Butterworth, you decide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code compiles (see http://ideone.com/celq1):

```
typedef unsigned int uint ;
int main()
{
    bool (*draw)(uint, uint, uint, uint, const char*);
    draw = reinterpret_cast<bool (*)(uint, uint, uint, uint, const char*)>(0x10057970);
    draw(20, 20, 14, 255, "Text");
}
```

But of course it doesn't run :-)
PS I changed `char*` to `const char*` to get rid of a compiler warning. It looks like `const char*` is what you want here, but it's not essential to the idea.

**Edited to add:** In fact, even this compiles, if you want to impress your friends:

```
typedef unsigned int uint ;
int main()
{
    reinterpret_cast<bool (*)(uint, uint, uint, uint, const char*)>(0x10057970)
      (20, 20, 14, 255, "Text");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for. :) -Compiles, and works as expected.

Answer (score 6):

You can always cast:

```
typedef bool (*funcptr)(uint, uint, uint, uint, char*);

funcptr draw = (funcptr)0x10057970;
```

or in C++:

```
funcptr draw = reinterpret_cast<funcptr>(0x10057970);
```

However, this is completely undefined behaviour.

Also, in general, there's nothing to stop the compiler moving the target function, or even eliminating it entirely if it doesn't see it being called explicitly.

Comment: Well, the address exist in an .exe I'm hacking, I should have mentioned that. (It's actually part of another DLL, it should be getting added to the export table at some time in the future, but for now, I have to access it like this. Or write my own, and GL text is a bit of pain to do yourself.) Thanks btw, I'll try this out. :)

Comment: You have inadvertently adopted TheMonster's unconventional syntax, using `(funcptr*)` instead of `(*funcptr)`. I hope the compiler you use is not so unconventional as to accept it!

Comment: I've seen asterisk(void asterisk), etc,. But never what you suggest, also, as I mentioned, I read about this method somewhere, but was curious about making it work with an address. (I have my reasons, and it should work fine, that function isn't going anywhere, trust me, it's been there for days now.)

Comment: I really don't see why this is being upvoted, as it doesn't really address the question, and admittedly invokes UB.

Comment: @Neil: All your negative comments just inspired me to vote it up too. What's eating you here?

Comment: @Neil: Other than my inadvertent syntax typo (now fixed), I think this does address the question, i.e. how to cast an integer to a function pointer.